# How to force the www. on heroku

Tags: python, django

I have my domain on infomaniak and my django application on heroku

my application work when i go to https://WWW.{{domain}} but i can't access to https://{{domain}} (without WWW.)

thanks

Comment: Isn't a simpler way to do this just making a redirect in your webserver to redirect `domain/whatever` to `www.domain/whatever`?

Comment: how to do this redirect on my heroku host?

Answer (score 0):

It should work without `www`.

In your Django app, in `settings.py`, be sure to include your domain name in allowed_hosts.

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["www.yourdomain.com"]`

That should fix it.